# What is the best way to check if an attribute exists and is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a common view that lists two different models. The only difference is that when setting the `link_to` action, one of the models has a `link` attribute and the other doesn't. I want to check if the `link` attribute exists, and if it does, check if it's set. I have the following which works, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

```
%li
  - if @element.has_attribute?("link") && @element.link
    = link_to @element.title, @element.link
  - else
    = link_to @element.title, @element
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence):

```
= link_to @element.title, (@element.link.presence || @element)
```

Or, if `@element` might not have `link` at all, you could use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try):

```
= link_to @element.title, (@element.try(:link) || @element)
```

Answer (score 14):

I believe you can just do `@element.attribute?` (e.g. `@element.link?`)
(I suppose we could call it "magic attributes".)

This checks for

- the attribute existing on the model
- the value not being nil

Exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Try using the attributes hash. This hash will return a `key => value` mapping of all of an activerecord object's attributes.

```
if @element.attributes['link']
  # Here we are
else
  # default
end
```

Comment: better yet: `@element.attributes.key?('link')`

Answer (score 1):

There is also [key?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.9/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) which is useful when checking if a property exists on the object, but would otherwise return `nil` or `false`.

For example:

```
a = { b: [] }

a[:b].presence # nil
a.try(:b) # nil
a[:b].present? # false
a.respond_to?(:b) # false

a.key?(:b) # true
```

So in this case:

```
%li
  = link_to @element.title, (@element.key?(:link) ? @element.link : @element)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%li
  = link_to @element.title, @element[:link] || @element
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Gerhard
In my humble opinion, this is the shortest / prettiest version of the code from the question. It does not contain a single extra code symbol.